# IE and Mixed content

Tags: internet-explorer, web, requirejs

I'm facing an issue with a public website we've been working on.

**The context:**
The website is served over HTTP, and every page contains an `iframe` which is served over HTTPS. The website also uses require.js as a module loader.

**The problem:**
Although the "normal" (understand included in the HTML) scripts load just fine over HTTP, dynamic scripts loaded by require.js throw a `SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by <HTTP file path>` on IE, no matter what version.

As a result, the users are presented with this message:
[image: IE information message]

Yes, the users can click on the `Show all content` button to force the JS files being loaded, but the experience sucks.

**Notes:**

- The scripts that throw the error are associated to the main page, and not the `iframe`
- The problem clearly is related to the secure `iframe` since if it's removed from the page, the errors disappear
- The problem is not present on either Firefox nor Chrome

**The questions:**

- Does anyone know why IE complains about JS files served over HTTP for a page also served over HTTP?
- Does anyone have a solution so the user is not presented with the message and all the scripts are loaded without the user doing any further action?

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick "fix" that the IE team specified in handling mixed content:

> specify the source of the page’s resources using protocol-relative
>   hyperlinks, of the form "//example.com/image.gif".  When the user
>   visits a secure page containing such a reference (e.g.
>   https://example.com/page.htm) the resulting URI will be evaluated as
>   https://example.com/image.gif.  On the other hand, if the user visits
>   the same page using HTTP, the resulting URI will be evaluated as
>   http://example.com/image.gif.  In this way, site developers can easily
>   build pages that work for either HTTP or HTTPS without introducing a
>   mixed content vulnerability.

More details can be found here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/06/23/internet-explorer-9-security-part-4-protecting-consumers-from-malicious-mixed-content.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/22/https-mixed-content-in-ie8.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but this won't resolve the problem since require.js create the `<script>` elements on the fly and specifies the path of the JS file as somthing like `/public/js/myJsFile.js`. Second, since the page is served over HTTP, protocol-relative links would be translated to HTTP.